# Installing mysql2 gem in vagrant via chef-solo

Tags: ruby, vagrant, mysql2, chef-solo

I'm trying to install mysql2 gem in my vagrant machine with chef solo. I am getting the following error

```
ERROR: mysql2_chef_gem_installer[default] (mysql2_chef_gem::default line 20) had an error:
Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe client for cookbook mysql
```

I have included the cookbook mysql and the dependencies are added in the metadata.rb

Following is the code snippet

```
mysql2_chef_gem_installer 'default' do
   type 'mysql'
   action :install
end
```

Could somebody explain what is it I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I couldn't get the cookbooks to install mysql2 gem but I found a workaround by installing the mysql2 gem by executing system commands 
eg: 
`execute 'install mysql2 gem' do`
   `command 'gem install mysql2'`
`end`